# Word Embeddings within Search in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, information-retrieval, word-embedding

Is it possible to make use of Word Embeddings within Apache Solr to perform a search, which would then contain results with similar *meanings* as opposed to regular string matches?

Comment: Have you looked at the OpenNLP integration support? https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/language-analysis.html#opennlp-integration - Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with running your content through other NLP tools and index the enriched data as payloads or as a separate field.

Comment: Within the link you send I couldn't find anything about representing words as embedding vectors, and performing the search on these similar vectors. Or is this not a possibility?

Comment: @MatsLindh Excuse me for asking again, but I've asked another question and I'm wondering if you have any experience with loading plugins into Apache Solr